# Raspberry pi, Linux, Google Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, raspberry-pi

We provide call and contact center solution for our customer, based on the info from our software principal, the web application is only support Google Chrome Browser, the problem is:
the customer only had Raspberry pi, they have confirmed us that Raspberry pi only had Chromium, few days ago we have tested the following

Raspberry pi (8GB) + Chromium --> unstable, the voice and video quality not good!, I pretty sure about their internet connection.

then we tried Raspberry pi (8GB) + Ubuntu-22 ARM64 and unfortunately this type of OS also doesn't support Chrome!

we also brought our own notebook (Windows 11, RAM8, I5) and it worked as expected!

we provide them 45 agent seats, meant they also have to invest 45 notebook + windows license (that doesn't make sense for me)

Any body can give me advice or idea what should I do?

We are now in the middle, the left side is our customer and the right is our software principal.

Our expectation is we want to keep them to use their Raspberry pi.

Note:
Hopefully this time superuser would not reject my message because I really don't want to have a product recommendation (I knew the rule)

Comment: There are very cheap alternatives that aren't notebooks. Any small low-end spec'ed miniPC is a lot more powerful than a RPi and can run desktop (as in X86_64) Windows or Linux and Google Chrome. If you know where to procure (China, obviously) and considering a volume purchase they'll end up almost as cheap as RPi. The problem with ARM based deices is indeed software availability. But as explained before Chromium should provide the same functionality.

Comment: And it isn't clear why you didn't test Chromium under Ubuntu (x86_64, PC or notebook) as that could have made a difference. Nor you mention what OS were running in the RPi before trying Ubuntu (Raspbian/Raspberry OS ?). Nor whether you tested a notebook with Ubuntu+Chromium. That would have ruled out Chromium as the culprit if successful. Very likely the limitation is the RPi rather than the OS or software (Chromium vs. Chrome).

Comment: The answer is the same. Google doesn’t build Chrome or distribute Chrome for the platform and architecture you are using. The one thing you should do is submit the same question after your original question was closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Chromebooks seem to work well, why not have them use those?  There are low end Chromebooks nowadays for less than $100, especially when purchased at volume.  Not only that, if you found a solution that works, the amount of time (read money) that you will invest searching for and testing other solutions will likely outweigh any cost savings you might find.  Engineering time is expensive.  Cut your losses and go with the Chromebooks.

Also, on a side note, for the money, Raspberry Pi's should never be used in a production-ish sort of environment.  There are far better solutions nowadays that cost much less.  In my experience, Raspberry Pi's are really only good for prototyping and small hobby projects, but tend to fall down (rather spectacularly) when deployed at scale.  There are exceptions to this, but it happens much more often than not.